# Convert bash function using wget to powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, loops, wget

I use a function to download files sequentially using filenames and URLs stored in a text file (space delimited).

```
while read FILENAME URL
do
    wget -c -O "$FILENAME""_fastqs.tar" "$URL" 
done < path/links.txt
```

I would like to convert this function to use it with powershell.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By all means, do it. `Import-Csv` and `Invoke-WebRequest` might prove useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the `Import-Csv` cmdlet deal with the input file:

```
Import-Csv path/links.txt -Delimiter " " -Header 'Filename','Url' | 
    ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest $_.Url -OutFile "$($_.Filename)_fastqs.tar" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Content path/links.txt | ForEach-Object { $dat=$_.Split(" ");Invoke-WebRequest $dat[0] -OutFile $dat[1] -PassThru }
```

Read the file with Get-Content. Read each line with ForEach-Object. Split the line into array dat using the Split function. Use Invoke-WebRequest to download the file using the indexes of the array dat as url and download file accordingly.